# if $\forall T \in S(T \neq Q)$ then $\bigcup S \neq Q $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can I proof:

"let $S$ a family of sets, and $Q$ a set, if $\forall T \in S(T \neq Q)$ then $\bigcup S \neq Q $"??

$\bigcup S:=\{y| \exists T \in S(y \in T)\}$

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Note that vast swathes of mathematics depend on this claim failing to be true, given the importance of open covers in anything with the least connection to topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding the answer is no. Just let $S=\{\{a\},\{b\}\}$ and $Q=\{a,b\}$.

Comment: ...but $\bigcup S=Q$ so the statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The counterexample $S= \emptyset$ and $Q = \emptyset$ also works.